# Bind Boolean value in Sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Anyone have idea about how to bind  Boolean in sqlite with objective - c.

i know how to bind int and string but i don't know about boolean value.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, id);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt,3 ,[message UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

but how can i bind `boolean` value.

Please help me.

Thanks you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQLite does not distinguish booleans from ints.  So you can just use bind_int.  The only real [storage classes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) are NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, and BLOB.  Note:

> "But as soon as INTEGER values are
>   read off of disk and into memory for
>   processing, they are converted to the
>   most general datatype (8-byte signed
>   integer)."